What is this statue from Iraq/Babylon, and what does the cuneiform on it mean?
This statue belongs to a family friend, who worked for the US Army Corps of Engineers in Iraq around the time of the 2003 invasion. He says that after he returned home, he received this statue in the mail from someone he worked with there.
It has a cuneiform inscription on the back, and we're interested in what the inscription means and what the purpose of the statue might have been (assuming it's authentic). We're also aware that it might have been looted or illegally excavated given how common that was at the time, but we have no specific reason to believe that was the case.
The statue seems to depict a standing, robed figure with its arms crossed over its chest. Here are some pictures:


The units on the tape measure are US inches (so it's ~6in/15cm tall). Here is the cuneiform inscription on the back. I am no expert on this time period, and don't even know what language this cuneiform encodes, but I'd guess it's Akkadian given how it was obtained and the simplicity of the graphemes:

What do the cuneiform mean and what would the purpose of the statue have been?

I don't suppose this friend's friend happens to own Hobby Lobby?

You should find a museum in your vincinity that presents objects from Mesopotamian antiquity, ideally with a department investigating provenance, and ask for help. As long as you can't exclude a case of looting, treat this as a potential criminal matter.

@ccprog OP seems to be in the US, so the nearest suitable museum may very well be in NYC even if OP is for example in Texas. This is a good idea but it seems quite likely to me that no such museum is anywhere within a couple of hours driving from where OP is.

The design reminds me a lot of the statue of Ebih-il of Mari. https://archeologie.culture.gouv.fr/mari/en/statue-ebih-il

Some general information can be assumed in respect to the last line of the question, "What is the purpose of the statue" and what the cuneiform inscription might mean.
What this item represents is a votive object. It would be made to present at a temple as an offering, with this class of object literally representing a worshipper praying to a deity. The Met has a good article discussing this type of object:

...the elite commissioned images of themselves to be carried into the
god’s presence. These statues embodied the very essence of the
worshipper so that the spirit would be present when the physical body
was not.

A paragraph shows this object has similarities in pose to others found (emphasis mine):

The votive statues are of various sizes and usually carved in gypsum
or limestone. They depict men wearing fringed or tufted fleece skirts,
and women wearing fringed or tufted dresses draped over one shoulder.
Many have inlaid eyes and painted hair. The statues are usually carved
with the hands clasped, right over left, at the chest or waist in a
gesture of attentiveness.

The purpose of the inscription on the back is also mentioned:

Some figures from Nippur have a cuneiform inscription on their back or
shoulder giving the name of the god and the profession and name of the
donor.

So my understanding would be that the upper inscription might represent the name of the deity being worshipped, while the lower inscription would indicate the person that the statue is representing.  You might compare this with the much later development of chantries where monks were essential paid to pray for the soul of an individual. This statue would represent the piety of the individual within the temple space, where only the priest could enter.

Thanks for your help! I'm accepting this answer (and I don't expect anyone who reads whatever particular era of cuneiform this is will stumble upon this post and have time to translate), but it would also be cool to know what the specific god and occupation were, and to narrow down the time period a bit. Would you happen to know of any lists of gods and/or occupations in Cuneiform with translations so I could try to visually match them myself? I figure gods will be easier than occupations because I've found that  (second to last character in first inscription) is the marker for "god".
